# I am trying to create a reduce function but when I need to call the function I don't understand what the first argument should be

Tags: python, function, reduce

```
def myreduce(anyfunc, sequence):

    result = sequence[0]
    for item in sequence[1:]:
        result = anyfunc(result, item)
    return result

myreduce(,[1,2,3,4])
```

Comment: The first argument should be a function that combines the list elements in some way.

Answer (score 1):

To access the syntax of operators (*, +, //, /, &, etc.), you need the operator library. For example, it looks like you want to write something like "myreduce(*,[1,2,3,4])" to use the multiple operator on the list. This is in the operator module.

```
import operator

myreduce(operator.mul,[1,2,3,4])
```

Of course, the function you just wrote is an already written function in the functools module.

```
from functools import reduce
import operator

reduce(operator.add,[1,2,3,4,5])
```

Answer (score 0):

The first argument should be the function that's being reduced. For instance, if you want to sum all the list elements, it should be a function that adds its two arguments.

```
myreduce(lambda x, y: x + y, [1, 2, 3, 4])
```

If you don't want a lambda, define a named function:

```
def add(x, y):
    return x + y

myreduce(add, [1, 2, 3, 4])
```

Comment: I was trying to avoid the lambda function but thanks for your help

Comment: You can use a named function as well, I've updated the answer.